# Python import works when running module but breaks when this module is imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have a directory structure like this:

```
source\
  main\
    bar.py
    run.py
  A\
    foo.py
```

`bar.py` has functions which `foo.py` needs, so I use `from bar import *`, which works, as I've given `foo.py` the correct path to find `bar.py`.  I verify this by running `foo.py` and calling any of the functions from `bar.py` without appending `bar` next to it.  For example, if `myFun` is defined in `bar.py`, I can simply call `myFun(...)` in `foo.py`.  This works all great so far.

`run.py` imports `foo.py`.  However, when I try to run a function from `foo.py` which in turn uses a function imported from `bar.py`, Python claims `myFun(...)` does not exist.  Note that `myFun` was originally defined in `bar.py`.

`NameError: global name 'myFun' is not defined`

The only way I managed to resolve this was to copy `myFun` into `foo.py`, but that is not really a solution.

Comment: Not sure if it'd work, but you could try make a function in foo.py that executes myFun, and if not, why not just import bar.py into the run.py file?

Comment: Please provide code snippets. It'll be easier to understand exactly the semantics you are using when importing.

Comment: Do you have a different `bar.py` hanging around? In `foo.py`, add `import bar;print os.path.abspath(bar.__file__)`. Also, in foo.py, add `from bar import myFun` ... that should trigger the error earlier (and closer to the fault).

Comment: In `run.py`, are you doing `from foo import *`? Do you use the `__all__` variable in foo (that would mask the stuff you import)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid fiddling with the import paths as long as you have other options.  In this case, create empty files `main\__init__.py` and `A\__init__.py` so Python recognizes these directories as packages, replace `bar` with `main.bar` in `foo.py` and run it from the top source directory.

Now, importing functions from `foo.py` to `run.py` should be as easy as:

```
from A.foo import fooFun1, fooFun2
```